# Different states depending on screen size with Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, hover, toggle, alpine.js

I need the  `x-on:mouseenter="itemActive = {{ index }}"` and `x-on:mouseleave="itemActive = false"` states to be `x-on:click="itemActive = {{ index }}"` and `x-on:click.away="itemActive = false"` on screen smaller than 768px. The code below works perfectly with the hover part for larger screens but can't seem to figure out how to make it work with different screen sizes.

I am using Twig, Tailwind and Alpine.JS.

```
<div x-data="{itemActive: false}" class="w-full pb-12 mt-5 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll md:flex md:flex-wrap md:w-auto md:mt-0 md:pb-0 md:overflow-visible">

  {% for item in menu.items %} {% set index = loop.index0 %}

  <div x-on:mouseenter="itemActive = {{ index }}" x-on:mouseleave="itemActive = false" class="flex flex-wrap w-full md:block md:w-auto {{ item.classes|join(' ') }}">

    <a :class="{'bg-gray-900' : itemActive === {{ index }}}" class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between w-full h-10 px-4 cursor-pointer md:h-14 md:justify-start md:w-auto" href="{{ item.link }}">
      {{ item.title }}      
      {% if item.children %}
        <span><i class="pl-2 fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
      {% endif %}
    </a>

    {% if item.children %}
    <div x-show="itemActive === {{ index }}" class="absolute z-10 w-48 bg-gray-900">
      {% for child in item.children %}
      <a class="flex flex-wrap items-center h-12 px-4 transition-colors cursor-pointer md:h-14 hover:bg-gray-700" href="{{ child.link }}" >
        {{ child.title }}
      </a>
      {% endfor %}      
    </div> 
    {% endif %}

  </div>

  {% endfor %}
  
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across with the same problem last night and I used the following approach:

```
  <div
    x-data="{ open: false, timeout: null}"
    x-on:mouseenter="
    width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if (width > 640) {
      open = true; clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
    "
    x-on:mouseleave="
    width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if (width > 640) {
     timeout = setTimeout(() => { open = false }, 100)
    }
    "
    @resize.window="
    width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if (width > 640) {
     open = false
    }
    "
    class="flex flex-col items-start justify-start sm:items-center w-full sm:relative sm:w-3/12 font-bold"
  >
    <div
      @click="open = !open"
      x-bind:class="open ? 'border-black border-b sm:border-0' : ''"
      class=" p-2 sm:p-0 w-full text-left sm:text-center hover:text-primary-light"
    >
      ABOUT US
    </div>
    <div x-show="open" class="flex flex-col items-start sm:items-center bg-white sm:border sm:border-black sm:rounded-lg w-full static sm:absolute sm:shadow-xl mx-auto top-0 mt-0 sm:mt-6 font-light pb-2"> 
      <a href={Routes.page_path(Endpoint, :index)} class="pl-4 sm:pl-0 w-full text-left sm:text-center pt-2 pb-2 border-b sm:border-b-0 sm:rounded-t-lg hover:bg-gray-100">
        Our Mission
      </a>
      <a href={Routes.page_path(Endpoint, :index)} class="pl-4 sm:pl-0 w-full text-left sm:text-center pt-2 pb-2 border-b sm:border-b-0 hover:bg-gray-100">
        Our Team
      </a>
      <a href={Routes.page_path(Endpoint, :index)} class="pl-4 sm:pl-0 w-full text-left sm:text-center pt-2 pb-2 border-b sm:border-b-0 hover:bg-gray-100">
        Join Us
      </a>
      <a href={Routes.page_path(Endpoint, :index)} class="pl-4 sm:pl-0 w-full text-left sm:text-center pt-2 pb-2 border-b sm:border-b-0 sm:rounded-b-lg hover:bg-gray-100">
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The key parts are the code inside the `x-on:mouseenter`, `x-on:mouseleave`, and `@resize.window`. We specify that the event is only be triggered when the width > 640. The `@resize.windows` is important when you expand the browser and reach a breakpoint, so we can reset the `open` variable, otherwise the state is dragged.

Comment: Sounds good! I solved it another way, but not the way I wanted to. Might try to implement your solution soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  {% for item in menu.items %} {% set index = loop.index0 %}
  <div 
    x-on:mouseenter="window.innerWidth >= 768 ? itemActive = {{ index }} : null" 
    x-on:mouseleave="window.innerWidth >= 768 ? itemActive = false : null"
    x-on:click="window.innerWidth < 768 ? itemActive = {{ index }} : null"
    x-on:click.away="window.innerWidth < 768 ? itemActive = false : null"
    class="flex flex-wrap w-full md:block md:w-auto {{ item.classes|join(' ') }}"
  >
    <a :class="{'bg-gray-900' : itemActive === {{ index }}}" class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between w-full h-10 px-4 cursor-pointer md:h-14 md:justify-start md:w-auto" href="{{ item.link }}">
      {{ item.title }}      
      {% if item.children %}
        <span><i class="pl-2 fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
      {% endif %}
    </a>
    {% if item.children %}
    <div x-show="itemActive === {{ index }}" class="absolute z-10 w-48 bg-gray-900">
      {% for child in item.children %}
      <a class="flex flex-wrap items-center h-12 px-4 transition-colors cursor-pointer md:h-14 hover:bg-gray-700" href="{{ child.link }}" >
        {{ child.title }}
      </a>
      {% endfor %}      
    </div> 
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

```
In the modified code, the `x-on` directives for `mouseenter` and 
`mouseleave` will only be executed if the screen size is greater than or 
equal to 768px. On the other hand, the `x-on` directives for `click` and 
`click.away` will only be executed if the screen size is less than 768px. 

Also, note that I added a conditional `null` value to the `x-on` 
directives, which is used to prevent the execution of the event when the 
screen size does not meet the condition.
```